# Jenkin not stop,restart,start systemctl custom application by script shell

Tags: jenkins

I have a service in systemctl. when Jenkin detects changed code, it build and run script 'systemctl restart ***Service.service'.
unexpectedly, jenkins announced: 
Failed to stop ***Service.service: Interactive authentication required.
See system logs and 'systemctl status ***Service.service' for details.

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop ***Service.service
Failed to stop ***Service.service: Interactive authentication required.
See system logs and 'systemctl status ***Service.service' for details.
```

i expect jenkin restart my service successfully
Thanh you

Answer (score 0):

Please use the next command

```
sudo systemctl restart ***Service.service
```